# Why are string identifiers often a set length?

Tags: url

For example: **http://youtu.be/naHkZpMkPA0**

You can look at websites likes imgur and youtube and popular link shorteners. My question is: let's assume it's the first ever submission, why would the id not follow an incremental pattern like `a, b, c ... ab, ac ... bda, bdb` etc. I can't think of a security risk as you can manipulate the id anyway.

Comment: I believe it's a hash of the url, not a "serial number" that keeps incrementing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, in the examples you give the ids are not unique to the user but are global. Therefore I don't see how you can expect your submissions to have sequential ids.

Secondly, whoever designed the id scheme could well have had security considerations in mind. To this end, they could well have thought it beneficial to make the ids hard to guess.

Comment: Couldn't you just keep track of the last submission and make the next submission's id subsequent to that one?